# Synthetic rubber coagulation

Tags: rubber

Is it possible to make crepe rubber from 
combining a synthetic rubber emulsion (Styrene Butadiene Emulsion) 
and a strong acid?

Comment: Could you provide a little more background, like why you think this combination might work?

Comment: Well as far as i know, crepe rubber is made by coagulating natural rubber using strong acids, i wanted to know if this applies to synthetic rubber emulsion sold by various building material companies.